# android:How to generate two app from one project, like google map(includes navigation, latitude)

Tags: android

Could anyone tell me how to manage the project, so it can generate multiple apps on the phone?
Like google map, one apk generates map, latitude, navigation.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An 'app' is just a collection of activities. Usually, there is just one main/entry one, but you can have multiple activities show up in the launcher by adding the `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` category to the activity's intent filter.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy to search, but by your wording you really seem lost. So I believe an answer is much more helpful here than a flag.

You need to include a LAUNCHER category as an intent-filter tag into each activity you want to appear in the launcher. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3610126/489607). This:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity2" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
         ....
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Credit goes to Ankit Jain, the original poster.